# How to transfer a Wordpress site from Bitnami (local host) to a live host online?

Tags: wordpress, local, bitnami

I'm finding out that developing my Wordpress child theme and website on my Bitnami local server was a HUGE mistake.

There's apparently no easy way to move it to a live 3rd-party host online.

- I've exported the bitnami_wordpress database (careful to select all the tables), then imported it into a new database on my hosting account.
- I've installed wordpress, and then replaced the wp-content folder with my own.
- I've adjusted the wp-config file.

Still, I lose all my pages.  I lose all my media library.  My widgets are no longer populated. And weirdly enough only SOME of my CSS seems to work.

And judging from the disparate and spotty "solutions" that I've found on the web, the only real solution seems to be (you guessed it): use Bitnami cloud hosting.  However, I'm already a Bluehost customer.

I've even tried 3 plugins so far, and none worked.  After all the work I've put into developing the child theme and populating it, this is a real nightmare.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (In simple terms - I don't know php...)  I'm completely lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To get my particular site working, I added the following code to my configuration file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

After adding the lines, my CSS and uploaded images came back.

Don't forget to replace example.com with your site's domain name.

I found that code at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL.

Actual user results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move all files with wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes into  your host.
2. Delete wp-config.php file.
3. Go to site URL EX: example.com and go through typical installation procedure.
4. Go to your database in your host and delete those 11 tables which have made.
5. Now you should export the local database and you should open it in any text editor and search and replace your local URL with new one.

Ex: localhost with example.com,  then import it to your database of real server.

Now It should work.